# Gnuplot - Windows terminal and save in png/pdf ... (not only .EMF)

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to draw graphics by piping the data from my C++ program to gnuplot.exe trough shell. I'm using the windows terminal and it is used exclusively with Windows OS.

However, I can only save the graphic as a .EMF file. How can I extend the windows GUI terminal to support more formats ?

[image: gnuplot windows terminal]

Comment: You need an answer ***specifically*** for the "Windows terminal" thingie rather than a description of a command line procedure `set term xxx; set out 'pippo.xxx; replot ; set out ''`, dont' you? BTW, what happens when you click on the floppy disk icon, do you have different options available?

Comment: yes, specifically for the Windows terminal. If I click on the floppy disk icon I can choose directly the location to save the EMF File.

Comment: @gboffi To be more precise, I would like to have different export format via the GUI, not via the command line procedure.

Comment: I hope to be wrong but ...  A possibility you could explore is to check if your binary supports one of the cross-platform terminals (`wxt` or `qt`) that are able to modify interactively the plot and offer a choice of different formats for the export of the modified plot.

Comment: @gboffi Thanks for the idea, I have recompiled my binary to support QT and it is better. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the windows GUI terminal can not be extended.

I have finally switched to the QT interactive terminal as recommended by @gboffi. This terminal permits to export the graph to :

- pdf
- svg
- bmp (via image)
- png (via image)

See bellow :

[image]

Note that this answer entails that the generated gnuplot.exe will be dependent to some external dlls ( QT5Core.dll ...)